# How do I access a method expression (struct function) from within another method expression in Go / Golang?

Tags: function, go, struct, model

I am trying to clean up the code in a Go / Golang project of mine. I thought that it might be idiomatic to create a model in an object-oriented way such that I can do, for example:

- `db.Users.GetID("john")` (to do a thing in the "users" table)
- `db.Purchases.GetTotal()` (to do a thing in the "purchasaes" table)

Etc. However, one problem with this is this is that the database functions can't call themselves if they need to.

Here's a tiny, contrived example of what I am talking about:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// A model that contains all of the structs for our database tables
type Model struct {
    Users
    Purchases
}

// A struct for functions that have to do with the "users" table
type Users struct {}
func (self *Users) Exists(id int) bool {
    // Check to see if the user exists
    // SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?
    return true // (omitted)
}

// A struct for functions that have to do with the "purchases" table
type Purchases struct {}
func (self *Purchases) Count(id int) int {
    // First validate that the user exists
    if db.Users.Exists(id) == false { // This fails <--------------
        return 0
    } else {
        // Get the count of that user's purchases
        // SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM purchases WHERE user_id = ?
        return 50 // (omitted)
    }
}

func main() {
    db := Model{}
    numPurchases := db.Purchases.Count(123)
    if numPurchases != 0 {
        fmt.Println("User #123 has", numPurchases, "purchases!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("User #123 does not exist!")
    }
}
```

This results in an error:

```
undefined: db in db.Users
```

If I changed it to just `Users.Exists` instead of `db.Users.Exists`:

```
./test.go:22: invalid method expression Users.Exists (needs pointer receiver: (*Users).Exists)
./test.go:22: Users.Exists undefined (type Users has no method Exists)
```

Note that, in this contrived example, it is pointless to be validating that the user exists. However, the point is that a DB function should have the ability to call some other DB function in case there is something actually important to validate.

How can I accomplish / work around this?

(Edit - Modified the code snippet for clarity.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you initialize the struct, you can fill it with self references. Since I am new to Go, I'm not sure if it is considered idiomatic, but it seems to work just just fine.

The fixed code snippet:
    package main

```
import "fmt"

// A model that contains all of the structs for our database tables
type Model struct {
    Users
    Purchases
}

// A struct for functions that have to do with the "users" table
type Users struct {
    db *Model
}
func (self *Users) Exists(id int) bool {
    // Check to see if the user exists
    // SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?
    return true // (omitted)
}

// A struct for functions that have to do with the "purchases" table
type Purchases struct {
    db *Model
}
func (self *Purchases) Count(id int) int {
    // First validate that the user exists
    if self.db.Users.Exists(id) == false { // This succeeds now <--------------
        return 0
    } else {
        // Get the count of that user's purchases
        // SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM purchases WHERE user_id = ?
        return 50 // (omitted)
    }
}

func main() {
    // Initialize the model and fill it with helpful self-references
    db := Model{}
    db.Users.db = &db
    db.Purchases.db = &db
    // In practice, you will want to do this in some sort of custom constructor, like:
    // var db Model*
    // db := Model.NewModel(db)

    numPurchases := db.Purchases.Count(123)
    if numPurchases != 0 {
        fmt.Println("User #123 has", numPurchases, "purchases!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("User #123 does not exist!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible in Go. `Users.Exists` is a *[Method Expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions)*. With these, you can take a method and convert it into a simple function type.

```
userExists := Users.Exists

user := User{}

// now userExists can be called as a regular function with
// first argument of a Users type
exists := userExists(&user, id)
```

As a result you cannot structure your model exactly like you have mentioned above.

Go is not a completely Object Oriented language and you should not try to replicate strictly OOP structures and idioms in it. In your case above, if you need an `Exists` function, you can always move `Users` into a separate package and define `Exists` as a function:

```
package user

type Users struct {}

// other methods on Users type

func Exists(id int) bool {
    // check to see if user exists
}
```

You can now make the following calls:

```
import "user"

user.Exists(id)
```

Comment: Well, I did manage to solve the problem, so I wouldn't be so quick to say that it isn't possible. ;) (See my posted answer.)

Comment: Can you perhaps give a working example online? Your code does not compile: https://play.golang.org/p/UHmDB39Xxv
Also, saying `self.db.Users.Exists(1)` is equivalent to saying `user.Exists(id)` in a much more contrived and illegible manner. In any case how would you now construct an actual user object? Would it now be a different type, resulting in two different user types?

Comment: My apologies. I've updated both the question code and my response code to make everything a bit more clear. It should also compile now.

Answer (score 0):

if you need field inside `Users struct`, you may use like `db.Exists(2)` or even `Users.Exists(db, 2)` both are valid. like this working sample code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Users struct {
    Ids []int
}

func (t Users) Exists(id int) bool {
    for _, v := range t.Ids {
        if v == id {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    db := Users{[]int{1, 2}}
    r1 := db.Exists(2)
    r2 := Users.Exists(db, 2)
    fmt.Println(r1, r2) // true true
}
```

you may use it like `db.Exists(2)` or even `Users.Exists(db, 2)`
both are valid. you may use `Users struct` just for grouping methods, like this working sample code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Users struct{}

var Ids = []int{1, 2}

func (t Users) Exists(id int) bool {
    for _, v := range Ids {
        if v == id {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    db := Users{}
    r1 := db.Exists(2)
    r2 := Users.Exists(db, 2)
    fmt.Println(r1, r2) // true true
}
```

you may use `UserExists(2)` when you do not need grouping, like this working sample code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Users struct{}

var Ids = []int{1, 2}

func UserExists(id int) bool {
    for _, v := range Ids {
        if v == id {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    r1 := UserExists(2)
    fmt.Println(r1) // true
}
```

so in your case this works fine:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Model struct {
    Users
    Purchases
}

type Users struct{}

var users Users

func (*Users) Exists(id int) bool {
    return true
}

type Purchases struct{}

func (*Purchases) Count(id int) int {
    if users.Exists(id) == false {
        return 0
    } else {
        return 50
    }
}

func main() {
    db := Model{}
    numPurchases := db.Purchases.Count(123)
    if numPurchases != 0 {
        fmt.Println("User #123 has", numPurchases, "purchases!")
    }
}
```

output:

```
User #123 has 50 purchases!
```